# Sorting arrays using a recursive binary search

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search

So I am reading in a txt file with a list of unsorted numbers...

```
14 36 9 87 2 5
```

My recursive method for the binary search is...

```
public static int bSearch(int[] a, int lo, int hi, int key)
 {
    int mid = lo+(lo + hi)/2;

    if (lo <= hi) 
        return -(lo+1); 
    else if (a[mid] == key) 
        return mid;
    else if (a[mid] < key)
        return bSearch(a, mid+1, hi, key);
    else 
        return bSearch(a, lo, mid-1, key);
}
```

I want to sort the values by implementing the recursive binary search. Can someone point me in the direction on how I would go about doing this.

Comment: Searching and Sorting are two different things, using one to do the the other would be tricky. You could look at quicksort which is a binary division sorting method.

Answer (score 1):

Why use binary search for sorting? If you are really looking for divide and conquer strategy, please have a look at merge sort.

Answer (score 0):

It is possiable to sort using binary search. Take a look: [Binary Searching and Sorting](http://jeffreystedfast.blogspot.in/2007/02/binary-insertion-sort.html)

Answer (score 0):

Binary search algorithm uses for searching.I guess you mixed up binary search with [quicksort algorithm](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Quicksort)